# Session tracking in Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat6, jsessionid

Is possible to switch off session tracking in Tomcat 6.
I mean, to avoid the creation of the cookie **JSESSIONID**.

Thanks Luis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put cookies='false' into contex definition in context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Context path='/myApplicationContext' cookies='false'>
  <!-- other settings -->
</Context>
```